# ¿Cómo capturar el evento de botón atrás dentro del onDetach?

Tags: android, eventos, onbackpressed

Tengo una variable en `SharedPreferences` que preciso borrar al destruirse el fragmento en todos los escenarios menos cuando se presiona el botón atrás. Mi idea era un `if` dentro del método `onDetach`, pero no sé cómo capturar el evento de ese botón dentro del método mencionado.

Comment: Hola DavidC, ¿qué lenguaje de programación estás usando? Supongo que Java, pero no se indica en la pregunta (android studio es un ide que permite programar en diferentes lenguajes). Y ¿podrías añadir un pequeño ejemplo de cómo lo has intentado hasta ahora? (no es necesario, pero podría servir de punto de partida para otros usuarios). Lee [ask] para más información. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Alvaro. Si, efectivamente estoy usando Java. Ejemplo no puedo ofrecer ya que de las formas que utilice ninguna compilaba. De todas formas subiré la respuesta una vez que consiga mi cometido. Gracias por las sugerencias

Comment: Comprendo. Una pregunta: ¿el evento de `onbackpressed` se ejecuta antes que el de `ondetached`? Diría que sí, pero no estoy seguro (no trabajo con android y Java); si es que sí, creo que tendría una solución para ti.

Comment: Claro, el orden es el que tu planteas, el problema es que el [onBackPressed] es un método del [Activity] mientras que el [onDetach] es propio del [Fragment]

Comment: Eso no importa... si no te importa usar una variable global que sirva de centinela.

Comment: ahh claro claro, no lo había pensado así

Comment: Dime si puedo asistir con algo o si necesitas ayuda. Saludos y suerte.

Comment: Pudiste resolver el problema?

Comment: disculpen la demora, me surgió una urgencia en un proyecto web y no llegue a resolverlo. quedó pendiente para la semana que viene

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es sobreescribir el metodo onBackPressed(), y evitar 
 el borrado de dicha variable del SharedPreferences antes de volver hacia atras.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Prueba a dejar esto en blanco, o a meter en el sharedpreference de 
    //nuevo la variable que no quieres que se borre aqui

    //ejecuta super.onBackPressed() para que finalice el metodo cerrando el activity
    super.onBackPressed(); 
}
```

Comment: No me reconoce el método que me sugieres. se pone el rojo el @Override

Answer (score 0):

Intenta crear una `interface` que notifique a tu `Fragment` desde el `Activity` que lo adjunta.

En tu `Activity` creas:

```
public interface OnBackPressedListener{
        void onBackPressed();
    }
```

Una variable privada:

```
private OnBackPressedListener listener;
```

y un método publico:

```
public void setOnBackPressedListener(OnBackPressedListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

Luego sobreescribes el metodo OnBackPressed propio de tu Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if(listener != null)
      listener.onBackPressed();
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Luego en Tu Fragment implementas la interfaz por ejemplo:

```
public class TuFragment extends Fragment implements TuActivity.OnBackPressedListener`
```

y haces esto:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((TuActivity)getActivity()).setOnBackPressedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ((TuActivity)getActivity()).setOnBackPressedListener(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        /** Aqui capturas el evento OnBackPressed antes de destruirse el Fragment en caso de que sea el peek del Stack, 
puedes modificar un boolean para cuando se llame onDetach() puedas ejecutar un if previniendo el borrado de datos.
        **/ 
    }
```

Nota: esto solo funcionara si el ciclo de vida de tu `Fragment` esta hecho de manera correcta en tu código. Es decir, si los métodos sobreescritos de `onPause()` y `onResume()` estan llamándose, para ello deberas realizar las transacciones del los `Fragments` de manera correcta. Esto asegurará que solo el `Fragment` activo obtenga la notificación desde la interfaz.

Comment: Te lo votan negativo sin especificar por qué no es adecuada cuando es como debe hacerse... vaya tela. Voto positivo =)

Comment: @Corpex asi es. Si el ciclo de vida del Fragment como dije en la nota esta bien implementado. Esta solución funcionaria con cualquier Fragment que en el momento este activo. Por eso los listeners en el onResume y onPause para evitar tener una referencia no nula al momento en que no se utilice. En mi caso cree una clase singleton que comunique los eventos de la Actividad a los Fragments para hacerla mas moldeable. Gracias.